# Stamp Coupling Improvement

Tags: java, oop, decoupling, stamp

I study programming in my college Stamp Coupling. We are learning system analysis and design. My classmate ask me the question, how to  solve Stamp Coupling? I ask Teacher who said "Use an interface to limit access from clients", but I still misunderstand.
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is way too broad to answer. You'll have to tell us the specific case in which you have to solve stamp coupling (preferably with relevant code).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't seem to understand SOLID principles and Design Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692126/cant-seem-to-understand-solid-principles-and-design-patterns)

Comment: @Eran Sorry, I miss the question, I already edit and add the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since the print method needs only the name, address and billing info of the Customer, you don't have to pass anything else to it.

You can define an interface:

```
public interface PrintableCustomer
{
    public ... getName();
    public ... getAddress();
    public ... getBillingInfo();
}
```

Now, let the `Customer` class implement `PrintableCustomer`.

The print method can now accept a `PrintableCustomer` instead of a `Customer`.

```
void print (PrintableCustomer customer)
{
    ...
}
```

Now `print()` only sees the properties that it needs.