# LINQ where condition with dynamic column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dynamic, linq-to-sql

I have this code

```
// IQueryable<General> query

if (columnName == "Column1") 
{
  query = query.Where(x => x.Column1 == searchValue);
}
else if (columnName == "Column2") 
{
  query = query.Where(x => x.Column2 == searchValue);
}
else if (columnName == "Column3") 
{
  query = query.Where(x => x.Column3 == searchValue);
}
else if (columnName == "Column4") 
{
  query = query.Where(x => x.Column4 == searchValue);
}
// next zilions columns to come
// ...
```

and my question is. How can i past x.Column as a parameter inside ".Where" condition ?

Comment: _"next zilions columns to come"_ You should refactor your datamodel. Why you have so many similar columns? Use another table instead. Then your query also becomes very simple and more efficient.

Comment: you can't..not in any simple way..but couldn't you instead of passing (searchValue, columnName), pass `Expression<Func<Typeofx, bool>> filterExpression` directly? used as `query.Where(filterExpression)` Where does the columnName, searchValue come from? why are they specified in that way

Comment: @TimSchmelter its columns of report table.. each column contains total different data. The purpose is let the user filter each column individually.

Comment: All the answers so far are for Linq-to-Objects. You should have indicated if it has to work for some other provider.

Comment: @bommelding thank you, i edited description tags. Its in .net core project, so it is using enity framework and SQL database.

Comment: @bommelding actually my answer should work with Linq-To-Sql (because I'm working with Expressions)

Comment: @AleksAndreev - the proof of a pudding is in the eating... Does it actually work?

Comment: @AleksAndreev it works, i just implemented it :) thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a predicate manually. Use this method:

```
public static Expression<Func<General, bool>> CreatePredicate(string columnName, object searchValue)
{
    var xType = typeof(General);
    var x = Expression.Parameter(xType, "x");
    var column = xType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == columnName);

    var body = column == null
        ? (Expression) Expression.Constant(true)
        : Expression.Equal(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(x, columnName),
            Expression.Constant(searchValue));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<General, bool>>(body, x);
}
```

Now you can apply your predicate:

```
IQueryable<General> query = //
var predicate = CreatePredicate(columnName , searchValue);
query = query.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: Not entirely sure, but aren't you missing an `Expression.Convert` for the constant value? I think I had to use it some time ago or it would throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) and extension methods. As a rough example:

```
public class Foo
{
  public int Column1 { get; set; }
  public int Column2 { get; set; }
  ...
}

public static class FooExtensions
{
  // I would use the actual type here instead of object if you know the type.
  public static object GetProperyValue(this Foo foo, string columnName)
  {
    var propertyInfo = foo.GetType().GetProperty(columnName);
    var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(foo);
    // as well as cast value to the type
    return value;
  }
}

...

query = query.Where(x => x.GetProperyValue(columnName) == searchValue);
...
```

As a side note, that is not a well-designed query because every time you add a column to your model, you'd need to update your `if`-`else`. It violates the O in [SOLID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692126/cant-seem-to-understand-solid-principles-and-design-patterns).

Comment: This won't work for example in Linq to Entities (I think we can assume the most used `IQueryProvider`), it can't translate the method to valid SQL

Comment: @AlexanderDerck, yes, you are correct. That is a valid point. Did not see the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Reflection to retrieve the property via name

```
x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName,BindingFlags).SetValue(x,value)
// propertyName = "Column1" for example
// BindingFlags are most likely Instance, Public and Property (IIRC)
```

or pass in the PropertyInfo directly into the method as a parameter. Your choice depends on the abstraction level you want to expose to consumers of your method.