# Trying to search db with Entity/Linq with conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity

So I have this action on my app i'm building. It needs to search the database based on some criteria and return the list of items meeting the criteria

My database context looks like this

```
    public DbSet<MarketCategory> MarketCategories { get; set; } //has .name
    public DbSet<InventoryAsset> InventoryAssets { get; set; } //has .name
    public DbSet<ItemCategory> ItemCategories { get; set; } // has .name
```

Each InventoryAsset has a column category and market that are related. So each item belongs to a category and each item also belongs to a market.

In my service I have the context in

```
  private readonly InventoryContext _context;
```

I am trying to write this method but i'm a little naive with entity and linq

```
 public IEnumerable<InventoryAsset> searchInventoryAssets(string query, string category, string market, string column)
    {
        return _context.//items that are part of the passed category, are also part of the passed market and where the passed column selected contains the passed query (such as InventoryAsset.ItemTitle == "red book")
    }
```

The item model:

```
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; } // + more things like upc/brand/price etc 
  public virtual ItemCategory Category { get; set; }
  public virtual MarketCategory Market { get; set; }
```

Both ItemCategory and MarketCategory are similar

```
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public virtual IEnumerable<InventoryAsset> CategoryAssets { get; set; }
```

If there's not like a single line of code I can write,  I was going to so something like

```
 var catItems = functionToReturnCatItems(category);
 catItems.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Market.MarketPlaceName == market);


 then do a if switch statement for each column in the db 
 if ( column == "Title"){ // search query for title...
 }
```

Idk if this is a good solution though

Comment: Please also show the class models.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you have a type-specific context `InventoryContext`. But assuming that your context looks like:

```
public class Context : DbContext {
    public DbSet<MarketCategory> MarketCategories { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<InventoryAsset> InventoryAssets { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<ItemCategory> ItemCategories { get; set; } 
}
```

and `_context` is an instance of `Context` class, something like the following should work:

```
public IEnumerable<InventoryAsset> searchInventoryAssets(string query, string category, string market, string column)
{
    var assets = from inventoryAsset in _context.InventoryAssets 
        join marketCategory in _context.MarketCategories on inventoryAsset.MarketCategory_Identity equals marketCategory.Identity
        join itemCategory in _context.ItemCategories on inventoryAsset.ItemCategory_Identity equals itemCategory.Identity
        select inventoryAsset;

    switch (column)
    {
        case "Title":
            assets = from inventoryAsset in assets where inventoryAsset.Title equals query select inventoryAsset;
            break;
        default:
            // throw or whatever suits
            break;
    }

    return  assets.ToList();
}
```

Or alternatively, you could use `Expression` for a more generalized approach (I haven't tested it):

```
public static Expression<Func<General, bool>> CreatePredicate(string columnName, object searchValue)
{
    var xType = typeof(General);
    var x = Expression.Parameter(xType, "x");
    var column = xType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == columnName);

    var body = column == null
        ? (Expression) Expression.Constant(true)
        : Expression.Equal(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(x, columnName),
            Expression.Constant(searchValue));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<General, bool>>(body, x);
}


public IEnumerable<InventoryAsset> searchInventoryAssets(string query, string category, string market, string column)
{
    return  (from inventoryAsset in _context.InventoryAssets 
        join marketCategory in _context.MarketCategories on inventoryAsset.MarketCategory_Identity equals marketCategory.Identity
        join itemCategory in _context.ItemCategories on inventoryAsset.ItemCategory_Identity equals itemCategory.Identity
        where CreatePredicate(column, query)).ToList()
}
```

source for `CreatePredicate` method: [LINQ where condition with dynamic column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52967031/linq-where-condition-with-dynamic-column)