# C# Using class specific member references that child "base" calls respect

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I'm currently working on a codebase and struggling to find an optimal and clean solution. I've removed the context of the problem to help simplify it to its root components. The `Scale` property is a simplification  for a more complex state of the class in the actual codebase. I have an idea (which I'll reference at the bottom) for how I could solve this issue - however the solution feels messy and just avoids the area I want to better understand.

**Class Hierarchy**

```cs
public class GreatGrandparent
{
    public virtual int Scale { get; set; } = 1;
    public virtual int GetTrueScale()
    {
        return Scale;
    }
}

public class Grandparent : GreatGrandparent
{
    public override int Scale { get; set; } = 2;
    public override int GetTrueScale()
    {
        return Scale * base.GetTrueScale();
    }
}

public class Parent : Grandparent
{
    public override int Scale { get; set; } = 8;
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public override int Scale { get; set; } = 4;
}
```

*Somewhere else in code:*

```cs
public class Main 
{
    Child aChild = new Child();
    int aChildTrueScale = aChild.GetTrueScale();
}
```

- Expected Result: `4` (4×1) (Refer to **Edit 1**)
- Actual Result: `16` (4×4)
- **Desired Result:** `64` (4×8×2×1)

I want a child to find its relative scale by taking in all factors of scale from its parents, so that would like:

`child relative scale = child scale × parent scale × … × base class scale`

How can I (if possible) define the `GetTrueScale` method once in the parent class to get the desired result - which all children inherit - to avoid continuously overriding the method with duplicate implementations (the exception being the GreatGrandparent).

**"Messy" Solution**

Define a separate property/field in each class, and continuously override the `aChildTrueScale()` method with a return of `ClassScale * base.GetTrueScale()` where the `ClassScale` is a different property on each Class.

**Edit 1**

The *expected result* was my initial expectation based on my understanding at the time - thinking that within a `base` call the *Scale* reference would <strike>respect the change in scope</strike> change value to match that of the `base` class. With some further testing it appears that regardless of  <strike>what scope</strike>  when a base method is called, the referenced `Scale` value is always from the initial objects <strike>scope</strike> (hence 4*4).

Is it possible to refer to properties based on their scope? So in a `base.GetTrueScale()` call, any references within that function call will be on the `base` scope. Or am I completely missing something/trying to over simplify children?

**Footnote**

I've got a a bit of experience with procedural programming around data science, however I'm fairly inexperienced with object-oriented programming so forgive me if I'm ignorant to some core concepts. I’m happy to help clarify anything, thanks for taking the time to look over my first question! ^-^

*(If anyone can think of a better title please let me know and I'll fix it up - was struggling to define the issue simply)*

Comment: Thing is, each of the classes in your hierarchy don't have different `Scale` properties. It's the *same* `Scale`. Do your `Scale` properties really need to be writable? How would you set the value of `Parent.Scale`, given an instance of `Child`?

Comment: You're also mis-using the term "Scope". I'm not sure what you're trying to refer to, but the scope of a variable is the region of code which can refer to it by name

Comment: @canton7 Yeah in this case `Scale` is a simplification for a Hashset of objects, however I understand what you're getting at. The Hashset isn't writeable (so `Scale` shouldn't be in this case either that's my fault in the question). I wanted to simply the problem but in essence any nth-child has a HashSet that is in Union with all its hierarchy HashSets. The issue is the sense of maintainability that I want to be able to edit the values of a parent class if the features of the program change, and have child be aware. Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: @canton7 Also thanks for highlighting my mis-use of "Scope", I was thinking in a runtime sense of the variables accessible to a method. I'm still learning alot and this is all new to me! ^-^

Comment: I guess my question still stands: in your real code, how are things added to a base class's `HashSet`?

Comment: They're only added during development, not during runtime so they are immutable (if I'm using that term correctly aha). So if parent HashSet was {"valueOne"}, and the child's HashSet was "{"ValueTwo"} then the method should return {"ValueOne","ValueTwo"}

Comment: Can you give us an actual example ([edit] something runnable into your question), rather than the over-simplified version you currently have? It's starting to sound like you actually just have a single `HashSet` which is added to by each sub-class, but I'd like to see something more concrete to be sure

Comment: I edited above to I include an example above sorry, but yes you would be correct, its single `HashSet` that is added to by each class where modifications in hierarchy are shown in children.

Comment: With this sort of hierarchy where each level maintains its own data, you probably don't want to use the *type system* to model the hierarchy but probably `Parent` and/or `Children` members of, potentially, a single type. Then each member of the hierarchy is an independent object.

Comment: I don't see any recent edits in your question? Do you mean [something like this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAFgNwFgBQUDMCBMcAglgN5ZyVwAOATgPYAuApgMYvBy3MCGw9AOwA2ATzgAJHgGcAFgGVmjADxIYAPjgzp8xXAC8cAcwDuACgCUGTFTgUquYhbuVy1m1S2yFjAHRFgwKYARABuPEIArswA8kZBls5wAL5YKZhYDlCEAEJwIMRkiQ7ZTm4uie6eOr7+gaHhUQAqxvTxVjZpSUA===)?

Comment: @canton7 omg yes that would be correct. I feel so dumb I was overcomplicating it... In the `int` example I would just keep multiplying it in each constructor to keep track of the "true" value seperate as well! Will have to test later to see if I can implement it and ensure each constructor in the hierarchy is called to add to the `HashList`.

Comment: One of a type's constructors will *always* be called. If you define multiple constructors, only one of them will be called, but you can chain them to ensure that a particular one is always called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments, it turns out that you don't need your `Scale` property to be settable (its value is fixed on construction), and you don't even need it to be virtual. You can just have a single property on the `GreatGrandfather` class, like so:

```
public class GreatGrandparent
{
    public int Scale { get; }
    public GreatGrandparent(int scale)
    {
         Scale = scale;   
    }
}

public class Grandparent : GreatGrandparent
{
    public Grandparent(int scale) : base(scale * 2) { }
}

public class Parent : Grandparent
{
    public Parent(int scale) : base(scale * 8) { }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(int scale) : base(scale * 4) { }
}
```

---

In your actual code, you're dealing with a `HashSet`. You could write something like this, where each child adds new items to the GreatGrandparent's `HashSet`:

```
public class GreatGrandparent
{
    protected HashSet<string> hashSet = new();
    public GreatGrandparent()
    {
         hashSet.Add("itemOne"); 
    }
}

public class Grandparent : GreatGrandparent
{
    public Grandparent()
    {
        hashSet.Add("itemTwo");
    }
}
```

Or pass down the items to add in the constructor chain (more expensive, but maybe neater?):

```
public class GreatGrandparent
{
    protected HashSet<string> hashSet;
    public GreatGrandparent(IEnumerable<string> items)
    {
        hashSet = new(items);
        hashSet.Add("itemOne");
    }
}

public class Grandparent : GreatGrandparent
{
    public Grandparent(IEnumerable<string> items) : base(items.Concat(new[] { "itemTwo" })) { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using the type system to model this hierarchy is a mistake. You're wanting `Child`, `Parent`, `GrandParent` to be separate, independent things. That doesn't suggest the `is-a` relationship that you typically expect in the type system.

So instead have:

```
public class Thingy {
    public int Scale {get;set;}
    public Thingy Parent {get;set;}

    public int GetTrueScale()
    {
        var current = this;
        var accumulator = current.Scale;
        current = current.Parent;
        while(current!=null)
        {
            accumulator = accumulator * current.Scale;
            current = current.Parent;
        }
        return accumulator;
    }
}
```

And then create each of your objects:

```
var greatGrandParent = new Thingy {Scale = 1};
var grandParent = new Thingy {Scale = 2, Parent = greatGrandParent};
var parent = new Thingy {Scale = 8, Parent = grandParent};
var child = new Thingy { Scale = 4, Parent = parent};
```

And you can now call `child.GetTrueScale()` and all levels of the hierarchy are taken into consideration.

Adding `Children` sets to `Thingy` and other more interesting behaviours is left as a exercise.

---

`Thingy` itself could also be an `IThingy` interface, if the different levels truly do require separate types.

Comment: @BadCodeWithAngie ^^ you may see this referred to as "composition over inheritence".

Comment: Thank you heaps while @canton7 's answer helped me solve the issue at hand this is definitely worth considering in the perspective of the actual implementation. I'll have a go at this and see how it works. Thank you heaps! ^-^

Comment: I want to note for anyone else who stumbles that while accepted answer was the most straightforward solution to my problem, this answer was also extremely helpful! I tested this method out on my actual solution, and used Hashset<T>.UnionWith() in the Thingy.GetTrueScale() implementation just fine! Great help, thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever ^-^

Answer (score 0):

The type hierarchy will be called in the order from `most base type -> most derived`.

As you do not have overriden methods in `Parent` then your `Scale` is not multiplied. That it is a reason why you got `16`. It is better to debug and see order of execution of your code.

You can add override `GetTrueScale()` method of class `Parent` to have desired value `64`. The whole code will look like this:

```
public class GreatGrandparent
{
    public virtual int Scale { get; set; } = 1;

    public virtual int GetTrueScale()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GreatGrandparent: " + Scale);
        return Scale;
    }
}

public class Grandparent : GreatGrandparent
{
    public override int Scale { get; set; } = 2;

    public override int GetTrueScale()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Grandparent: " + Scale);
        return Scale * base.GetTrueScale();
    }
}

public class Parent : Grandparent
{
    public override int Scale { get; set; } = 8;

    public override int GetTrueScale()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Grandparent: " + Scale);
        return Scale * base.GetTrueScale();
    }
}
```

and `Child` class:

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    public override int Scale { get; set; } = 4;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just OP's "Messy" solution, which they already know about?

Comment: Yeah I didn't mean discredit it as a solution by describing as "Messy" just to imply it *felt* tedious redefining the same functionality, and easily broken if another contributor inherited from my class and didn't correctly override the method with the same implementation.

Comment: @canton7 yeah, it is. I just wanted to show why it happens.

Comment: @BadCodeWithAngie if another developer breaks overriden methods, then developer breaks [Liskov substitution principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle) of [SOLID principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692126/cant-seem-to-understand-solid-principles-and-design-patterns)

Comment: Oh I've heard of the SOLID principles before, but haven't looked into them thank you for the link! Its probably worth me not worrying too much about people incorrectly using my code

Comment: @StepUp Yeah that was my intention, it was just late at night for me! Thank you for your answer and a reminder! ^-^