# Passing Methods vs Generic Objects vs Event Specific Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, design-patterns, mediator

I often reach a crossroad in my code when it comes to passing methods vs generic objects vs specialised objects. Let me explain.

I am using the mediator pattern. I have DAO's which have generic methods based on a specific entity of the database it's targeting.If a method is targeting that specific entity I am putting it in that class. Sometimes the entity targeted is a table, other times it's a column within a table depending on whether this DAO class starts to be complex or not and needs breaking down. Then I have service type classes where it receives the DAO as the dependancy. This is an additional layer but it prevents me from passing my DAO classes directly into a mediator. This is so that I can unit test each class outside of the main meditator and call methods from each service class inside the mediator. This also allows me to potentially pick service objects which mediate together and pass that mediator into the main mediator if my dependancies start to grow.

However I often struggle when deciding upon the next step. Do I

1. pass the whole service object to the mediator giving it access to things it never intends to use. Ive read this goes against the Least Privilidge principle. Like this

   ```
   const turn = new ServerTurnMediator(
    new DiceService(DiceDAO),
    new PlayerMoneyService(PlayerMoneyDAO)
   )
   ```
2. Pass only methods from the specific service class to the mediator using and bind the methods I am passing in to the instance of the service object like this :

   ```
    const playerMoneyService = new PlayerMoneyService(PlayerMoneyDAO);
    const methodFromPlayerMoneyService = playerMoneyService.addMoneyToPlayer.bind(playerMoneyService);

    const turn = new ServerTurnMediator(
     new DiceService(DiceDAO),
     methodFromPlayerMoneyService
    )
   ```

here I pass methodFromPlayerMoneyService into the mediator class that requires it. If the mediator then needs 3 other methods from this service objects shall I repeat this binding process for each method?When is this too much ?

3. Start to create more event specific service objects that take in the DAO but rename the service objects around what they are trying to achieve and then pass the service object in full into the mediator. The methods are cohesive and are all referenced and possibly used in specific situations within the mediator class and there are no derelict methods within the class for the given mediator its passed into. If I did this I could use either inheritance or composition to extend each event specific class so that I prevent repeating methods in different event specific classes.

   ```
   const turn = new ServerTurnMediator(
    new DiceService(DiceDAO),
    new PlayerMoneyIncreaserService(PlayerMoneyDAO)
   )
   ```

This also feels like I am adhering to SRP more, but suddenly I will need a lot more classes specific to each event that occurs rather a single service object.

4. I could do the same as 3 but also create the same inheritance hierarchy or composition within my DAO classes so that the correct service object receives the DAO that has access to the functionality the service object is trying to achieve.

I am using interfaces where appropriate and my service classes often receive different DAO implementations with the same named methods or abstract methods.

Is there a right or wrong answer here or any specific moments that scream out for refactoring ? If so then why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why not option 4 where my Dao’s are also event specific where one
> service object accepts one Dao which completes the db functionality
> when called from the service class? Rather than the event specific
> service class accepting a Dao with methods it may not need ?

Having known this information, I would stay with the fourth option because it is a way to encourage use [SOLID principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692126/cant-seem-to-understand-solid-principles-and-design-patterns) in code. It would also look like [Traditional "N-Layer" architecture applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#traditional-n-layer-architecture-applications)

> This also feels like I am adhering to SRP more, but suddenly I will
> need a lot more classes specific to each event that occurs rather a
> single service object.

yeah, you are right. However, when your code has less lines of code, it is:

- easier to read it for future readers (this person can also be you in two weeks)
- easier to make changes in it
- easier to write tests
- easier to give name for methods and classes

> If I did this I could use either inheritance or composition to extend
> each event specific class so that I prevent repeating methods in
> different event specific classes.

yeah, you are right. You can read more here [when to use composition or inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Comment: That’s fantastic advice thanks. Why not option 4 where my Dao’s are also event specific where one service object accepts one Dao which completes the db functionality when called from the service class? Rather than the event specific service class accepting a Dao with methods it may not need ? Why should I keep my Dao generic where I each Dao targets an entity within the database rather than be event specific like my service classes ? Won’t I still have the naming issue within the Dao if I don’t ? Thanks again

Comment: @KevinGreetham without code it is really hard to say, but generic repository is a not way to go because sometimes it violates Interface Segregation Principle. So it is better to create specific repositories.

Comment: @KevinGreetham `Why not option 4 where my Dao’s are also event specific where one service object accepts one Dao which completes the db functionality when called from the service class?` yeah having known this additional info, the fourth option is more preferable

Comment: Great, slowly I’m Understanding. So is there ever a time to have generic Dao’s where it consist of multiple different methods altogether in one DAO class because it targets a specific entity e.g. addUser getUser DeleteUser etc or should this type of class not exist and I should have event specific classes everytime I want a specific event to occur ?  unless of course this each method has a chance of being called within the same event having taken place. E.g if score > 5 deleteUser else addUser then I assume this would belong in the same class.

Comment: @KevinGreetham I wouldn't use Generic Repository at all because  [Not every entity can be deleted, not every entity can be added, not every entity has a repository. Queries vary wildly; the repository API becomes as unique as the entity itself.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1231473/1646240)

Comment: Last question - I posted a watered down version of my concept. There are many more dependancies involved. As I was implementing this I have noticed that my Dao classes now target different entities on the database which if on the client side this would be a big no no as methods target only the properties within their class. So do you think my service objects should receive event specific Dao’s but where the Dao’s are still targetting specific entities within the database ?  And each service object should also receive the one Dao specific to that entity ? Meaning I have event specific 1/2

Comment: 2/2 Dao’s but still for a single entity? Then pass the Dao to the serv obj and then peform the mediation between all service objects within the mediator? Or shall I have a Dao obj that completes all the functionality across multiple entities for the specific event that has taken place ?  I’m thinking not to do that and instead have one specific  Dao per entity that includes the methods I want to achieve the functionality for that specific event and each service object receives the this Dao and the mediation berteeen service objects occurs in the mediator class that uses data from serv obj ?

Comment: @KevinGreetham it is really hard to say without seeing a code. But rule that I use is one repository per entity. Sometimes you can join other entities to your entity. If you are struggling, you can ask new question and community will try to help you

Comment: You’ve probably just answered my question. So each entity has just one repository but that repository could be from a single class or a class contaiining composition of others or an inherited class but the base class and all other classes inherited from target the specific entity also? Is that what your saying ?
As a side note - I do some of my business logic on the database rather than all on the app server which so I regularly peform joins and sub queries but I keep the method that does this within the repository that updates the specific entity or gets data from that entity.

Comment: @KevinGreetham I am scared I will give you a wrong advice because it is really hard to say without seeing code. Could you ask a question and send a link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77995643/one-dao-per-entity-vs-multiple-daos-per-entity

Answer (score 1):

What are you asking is probably interfaces. An interface as an abstract class with all methods being abstract.

In JS you can implement any interface mocking as you want.

In this fast implementation I don't use abstract classes. If you need abstract classes as interfaces just throw any error on calling an not-overridden interface's method through Proxy.

So you provide interfaces to your mediators and they are restricted to use only provided interfaces.

Note that returning bound to `this` methods isn't good since you can re-bound it. That relates to your second approach too. So a more complex Proxy or object with smart prototypes should be returned from `getInterace()`.

```js
class Int1{
  method1(){
    console.log('method1 of Int1');
  }
}

class Int2{
  method2(){
    console.log('method2 of Int2');
  }
  method3(){
    console.log('method3 of Int2');
  }
}

function implement(self, ...interfaces){

  let proto = self;
  while(proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto)){
    if(Object.getPrototypeOf(proto).constructor === Object){
      break;
    }
  }
  for(const int of interfaces){
    Object.setPrototypeOf(proto, proto = new int);
    proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
  }
  Object.defineProperty(self, 'getInterface', {
  get(){
    return function(int){
      let proto = self;
      while(proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto)){
        if(proto.constructor === int){
          const props = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Object.getPrototypeOf(proto));
          delete props.constructor;
          const selfProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(self);
          for(const name in props){
            if(Object.hasOwn(selfProto, name)){
              props[name] = selfProto[name];
            }
            return new Proxy(self, {
              get(target, prop){
                if(prop in props){
                  if(typeof self[prop] !== 'function'){
                    throw new Error('Requested interface prop isnt a function');
                  }
                  return self[prop].bind(self);
                }
                throw new Error('Method ' + prop + ' doesn\'t exists on interface ' + int.name);
              }              
            });
          }
          break;
        }
      }
      return null
    }
  }
});
}

class Test{
  constructor(){
    implement(this, Int1, Int2);
  }
  method1(){
    console.log('overridden method1() of Int1');
  }
  method2(){
    console.log('overridden method2() of Int2');
  }
}

const test = new Test;
test.method3();
const int = test.getInterface(Int1);
int.method1();
int.method2();
```

Comment: Whilst not forcing an interface where an error would be thrown if not adhered to , I feel like I’m using Interfaces a lot of the time already by passing in a different Dao into my service classes and then providing methods in the service class from the mediator which invokes methods of the passed in Dao. The methods of each Dao are named the same to adhere to the interface and are public methods which invoke private methods from the DAO. Kind of like a facade. However most Of the time each Dao and each service class provides totally different functionality to others Dao’s and service 1/2

Comment: 2/2 classes. So a lot of the time I am just creating a service class, passing the required Dao into it and then this service class itself is passed into a specific mediator and all mediators are stored in an array of mediators , all with a specific peformAction method which completes the medaiton if this it’s mediator is picked out from the array and mediates using the service objects it receives which have interfaces and may have different implementations when calling the interface depending i. What Dao is passed to the service class

Comment: @KevinGreetham I just tried to hint you about possible ways to solve the interface problem. i hope that helped a bit to broaden your view of the problem. Regarding myself I would avoid a complex imperative OOP approach - managing the state is very difficult. Currently I'm using reactivity (Vue) and would look into Streams (creating different pipe/mutex logic). These ones tend to more functional approach. I think a mixed OOP/functional (for the state) approach is more manageable